# ContactAccessLevel is 'Read' on AccountShare object but user cannot access the contact still?

Tags: sharing, contact, owd

I have a user who is trying to view a "Contact A" related to "Account A" and here are the settings.

1. User has read access for the "Account A" and all the contacts related to "Account A" as per the record in AccountShare object for this user:

> ```
> +--------------------+--------------------+----------+
> | AccountAccessLevel | ContactAccessLevel | RowCause |
> +--------------------+--------------------+----------+
> | Read               | Read               | Manual   |
> +--------------------+--------------------+----------+
> ```

2. OWD setting for Contact object is `"Controlled by Parent"`
3. There is no record in `ContactShare` object for the user but I think it does not matter because user already has read access as per `ContactAccessLevel` field value from the `AccountShare` object.
4. I have checked this [salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004005&language=en_US&type=1) and I am not sure it matters because user already has read access for all the contacts related to "Account A" as per the record in `AccountShare`  object.

**EDIT:**

1. I checked the `UserRecordAccess` and it shows `MaxAccessLevel` = `None` for the contact.
2. Yes, user profile has Read and Edit access to Contact object.

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Aren't 3 and 4 the same questeion?

Comment: Yes, I am repeating the same thing in #3 and #4 but in different context so that others know why I think user should still have access to view the contact.

Comment: What happens if you (as admin) do this in Developer Console Query: `SELECT MaxAccessLevel, RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = '005...' AND RecordId = '003...'`?

Comment: Do the user has read access on Contact in profile?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I updated question but `ContactAccessLevel` shows "Read" for the user for the Account. What does this field exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to mention that it was for Community user.

As per salesforce documentation for contact object:

> **Special Access Rules**
>   Customer Portal users can access only portal-enabled contacts.

I had to enable the contact as portal user and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Object Reference Guide of Salesforce and Force.com the definition of the field "ContactAccessLevel" as follows:-

> Level of access that the User or Group has to contacts associated with the account. The possible values are:
>
> • None
>   • Read
>   • Edit
>
> This field must be set to an access level that is at least equal to the organization’s default
>   ContactAccessLevel. This field can't be updated via the API if the
>   ContactAccessLevel field is set to “Controlled by Parent.” You can't update this field for the associated account owner using the API. You must update the account owner’s ContactAccessLevel via the Salesforce user interface

So the field is very much related to the sharing object model. I would like to interpret the technical specification as the Contact can be associated with the single user or we can create the group of users and associate this contact with the newly created group.

The Link - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/object_reference.pdf

Comment: I read the documentation on this field but it is still not clear. What do you think is the problem in my case?

Comment: Can you run the query specified by the @SfdcFox and get the result? The query result(s) is going to clarify the issue I believe.

Comment: I ran that query and updated the question with the result.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to check the profile and the object permission of the user. There is something missing in sharing settings.

Comment: :) I checked the profile of the user and that profile has read and edit access to contact object. This also I updated in the question.

Comment: Have you checked whether do you have sharing criteria enabled for your org?

Comment: If so, please do the recalculate. I am sure the issue is lying with the object permission and nothing else.